# With applicative order, what order are the arguments evaluated? Left to right or right to left?

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

In SICP part 1.1.5 *The Substitution Model for Procedure Application* I am curious about the applicative order of evaluation.

I understand that applicative order evaluates the arguments before applying the outer procedure.

My question is what order does it go through the arguments?

For example,

```
(+ (+ 2 1) (/ 10 2))
```

Will `(+ 2 1)` or `(/ 10 2)` get evalutated first?

Comment: `define`s are not just side notes to be used later. they are actual computation actions, defining the specified variable right then and there.

Comment: I have edited the post with a more suitable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are still on chapter 1 of the book. Rest assured that the rest of the book will explain this to you in greater detail. For now, you may be interested in this [footnote from section 3.2.1 *The Rules for Evaluation*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-21.html#footnote_Temp_342):

> ... this order [left to right or right to left] should always be considered to be an **implementation detail**, and one should **never write programs that depend on some particular order**. For instance, a sophisticated compiler might optimize a program by varying the order in which subexpressions are evaluated.

Later chapters discuss this question is increasing detail. For example:

- [Exercise 3.8](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-20.html#%_thm_3.8): "Define a simple procedure `f` such that evaluating `(+ (f 0) (f 1))` will return `0` if the arguments to `+` are evaluated from left to right but will return `1` if the arguments are evaluated from right to left"
- [Exercise 4.1](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_thm_4.1) - Change the order of evaluation in the metacircular evaluator.
- [Section 5.4.1 *The Core of the Explicit-Control Evaluator*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-34.html#%_sec_5.4.1) (subsection *Evaluating procedure applications*) - Shows how procedure application can be implemented in an explicit control evaluator. Here you can clearly see how the details of the argument-evaluation loop determine the evaluation order.

Comment: Note that a "sophisticated compiler" doesn't require the language **specification** to leave such an order undefined. A sophisticated compiler can work out when the actual order can be rearranged without changing the result that is required by the left-to-right order.

Comment: In C, the order of evaluation is specified because, historically, that allowed the development of **dumb compilers**. It was historically the C programmer's job to perform sophisticated optimizations; the compiler's job was just to very basic optimizations: select good instructions, make good use of registers, and avoid obvious waste (like jumping to unconditional jump instructions).  Function calls were compiled in the order that was convenient for the calling conventions. E.g. if the leftmost argument needed to be pushed onto the stack first, then that was evaled first.

Answer (score 1):

It is not specified.

In subsection [`procedure calls`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-12.html#node_sec_9.1), you can find the very specification.

> When a procedure call is evaluated, the operator and operand expressions are evaluated (in an unspecified order) and the resulting procedure is passed the resulting arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific example, `x` is evaluated before `y` since the two `define` are evaluated in sequence.

In a function call, like: `(+ (+ 2 3) (- 4 5))` the order of the evaluation of `(+ 2 3)` and `(- 4 5)` is unspecified in Scheme, as from the other answer. while in other lisp languages, like in Common Lisp, is from left to right.

Comment: So is it random?

Comment: It could be random, or in any other order. Unspecified means only that you *cannot* assume any order when you write a call, maybe the order could be different in different calls.

Comment: @joejoemac By not specifying the order you are allowed to choose one of many paths to expand, but there is a requirement that it should be consistent. Thus it will not be random.